# Unable to import org.tmatesoft in Android Studio gradle

Tags: svn, gradle, android-studio

Various posts here have shown importing svnkit from tmatesoft like below, and this runs fine in CLI but when in Android Studio both sync and running produce error on  `import org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN;`

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'
        classpath group: 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit', name: 'svnkit', version: '1.7.11'
    }
}

import org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN;

project.ext.SVN = SVN;

def _disableSystemExitCall = {
    System.setSecurityManager(
            new SecurityManager() {
                @Override public void checkPermission(java.security.Permission perm) {}
                @Override public void checkExit(int status) { throw new SecurityException(); }
            }
    );
};



def _enableSystemExitCall = { System.setSecurityManager(null); };

/* for certain scenarios might be useful to share these closures with build */
project.ext.disableSystemExitCall = _disableSystemExitCall;
project.ext.enableSystemExitCall = _enableSystemExitCall;

project.ext.doSvnMain = { String... aSvnArgs ->
    _disableSystemExitCall(); /* stop SVN.main from doing a System.exit call */
    try {
        SVN.main( aSvnArgs as String[] );
    } finally {
        _enableSystemExitCall();
    }
} ;

task AAAA << {
    doSvnMain( 'info', "mySVNUrl" );
}
```

Using 
Gradle - distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip
Android Studio - 1.0.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this search](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cfc%3A%22org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN%22), there is no class `org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.SVN` in any package of `org.tmatesoft.svnkit` org.

`svnkit-cli` of an old org `org.tmate` used to have it long time ago, but not the new versions and the new org.

Also, the artifact-id that you use is wrong, it should be `svnkit-cli`. All in all, that's the dependency declaration:

```
compile 'org.tmatesoft.svnkit:svnkit-cli:1.8.7' //newer version that the one you looked for.
```

And the classes that you need are:

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVNCheckoutCommand
org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVNCommandEnvironment
org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVNDeleteCommand
```

Comment: I tried those classes and AS still complains on the "tmatesoft" part in editor and on sync it produces error: `Error:(30, 0) Cause: startup failed:
build file '.../build.gradle': 30: unable to resolve class org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVNCommandEnvironment
 @ line 30, column 1.
   import org.tmatesoft.svn.cli.svn.SVNCommandEnvironment;
   ^

1 error`

Comment: Did you also fix the dependency declaration name to the correct one?

Comment: Ah ha! That seems to have fixed it! Thanks for your help.

Comment: AS still has hover-error for "tmatesoft" but sync/build and run is successful.